# How to change color of a HTML table (dynamically created) cell based on a value?

Tags: html, jquery

I have the following function which generates a table dynamically. Based on a certain value of a cell, I want to color the cell red.

```
function makeTable(container, data) {
            var table = $("<table/>").addClass('table table-striped');

            $.each(data, function(rowIndex, r) {
                var row = $("<tr/>");

                $.each(r, function(colIndex, c) {

                    row.append($("<t"+(rowIndex == 0 ?  "h" : "d")+"/>").text(c));

                    if( $.trim(c.toLowerCase() ) === "validated" ){
                        console.log("Paint it red"); 

<!-- this condition works and I do see "Paint it red" in the console. I tried multiple things at this stage, without success, to color the cell or the entire row red. I do have an inline stylesheet declared in the HTML, but I do not know what should I use it on. 

                    }else {
                        console.log("Leave it alone");

                    }                   
                });
                table.append(row);

            });

            return container.html(table);

        }
```

Comment: are you able to make use of CSS? you can add a class to your cell/table header before appending if that's the case, then use CSS to style the class (i.e. not inline CSS using the style attribute)

Comment: Thanks for your response. On what should I apply the CSS on, I tried. c.addClass('error') but got an error.
That's my CSS declared in the same HTML.
 
<style>
        .selected{
  background-color:green;
        }   
        .error{
  background-color:red;
        }
    </style>

Comment: that's because `c` is most likely a string containing your cell text! not a jquery element that you can call addClass on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call addClass() on the jquery element:

```js
function makeTable(container, data) {
   var table = $("<table/>").addClass('table table-striped');

   $.each(data, function(rowIndex, r) {
      var row = $("<tr/>");

      $.each(r, function(colIndex, c) {
         var cellMarkup = "<t"+ (rowIndex == 0 ?  "h" : "d") +"/>";
         var cell = $(cellMarkup); // now you have a jQuery element to call addClass on!
         cell.text(c); // sorry I forgot to put back your cell text

         if( $.trim(c.toLowerCase() ) === "validated" ){
            cell.addClass("error");

         } else {
            cell.addClass("selected");

         }
         row.append(cell);

       });
       table.append(row);

    });

    return container.html(table);
}
```

Comment: One more question. I can have "validated" value in a couple of cells. How can I ensure that the code checks only a specific column for that value?

Comment: You could go by `colIndex` if your column order won't change for the next few years

(`if (colIndex == 0 || colIndex == 2) { 
  // put your validated check here 
  // will only run the check in first and third column
}`)

That's the hacky way. But if you'd prefer something more "solid", I'll need to see the structure of the `data` variable to advise further

Comment: Here is how my columns are. The "validated" check will only be on "WorkFlowStage" column                                                                      
TripID --- OrgID --- UserID ---- DeviceID  ----  Topic ---- MsgTS --- WorkFlowStage

Can I use the column name in the validated check condition? Something like
if colindex['WorkFlowStage'] && ($.trim(c.toLowerCase() ) === "validated").

Comment: I put the "hacky" fix and it works. Many thanks again
if(colIndex == 6){
                        if( $.trim(c.toLowerCase() ) === "error" ){
                            console.log("Paint it red");
                            cell.addClass("error");
                        }
                }